# C program runs well in Windows but when run on Ubuntu it is not asking for string?

Tags: windows, c++, c

My simple code for getting info from user & print the same works fine with Windows OS (on Dev C++) but But its not asking for string when run on Ubuntu (tried Terminal/Dev C++ via WINE/Code Blocks)

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   void display();
   struct book
  {
         int isbn;
         char name[25];
  }b[5];

   void PUSH()
   {
        int top;
        for(top=0;top<5;top++)
        {
        printf("Enter the ISBN no:");
        scanf("%d",&(b[top].isbn));
        printf("Enter the name:");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(b[top].name);
        }
   }
  main()
  {
             PUSH();
             display();
  }
  void display()
  {
      int i;
      for(i=0;i<5;i++)
      {

      printf("----------------\nISBN no: %d",(b[i].isbn));
      printf("\nBook Name: %s \n",(b[i].name));
      }
      printf("----------------\n");
  }
  void POP()
  {
       int i;
      for(i=0;i<5;i++)
      {

      printf("----------------\nISBN no: %d",(b[i].isbn));
      printf("\nBook Name: %s \n",(b[i].name));
      }
      printf("----------------\n");

  }
```

Output on Ubuntu:

```
   Enter the ISBN no:23
   Enter the name:Enter the ISBN no:
```

After i input 23 it has to ask for the name of the book but its skipping that part & again asks for next isbn no.

After some blind retries I found that when gets(b[top].name); gets(b[top].name); was used twice like this it worked fine....

My question is why is it so.? How to make ubuntu compile & run programs that run fine on windows?

Answer (score 6):

This is really because your C code is broken, its not the fault of Ubuntu or anything else.

Here's a few tips on how to fix it to work though, and how to compile it.

1. `system("pause");` *don't do it.* Avoid system calls, as they hard-code a requirement of the end system (which doesn't exist on Linux)
2. `gets(b[top].name);` should be replaced by `scanf("%s", &b[top].name);` which is a more reliable way of taking string input.
3. `main()` is **invalid** you should replace `main()` with `int main()` and replace `system("pause");` with a simple `return 0;` to make your C standards-compliant.

*How to compile*

Compiling in Linux is much more simple than windows (for small programs like this).

- Open a command line.
- `cd ~/your/code/`
- Compile with this command: `gcc -Wall --pedantic -o my_program my_program.c`

  - If this command fails, you need to run `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

*And lastly some important advice:* Dev C++ died out in 2005 - On windows, switch to Visual C++ 2010 Express, on Linux use Eclipse or a text editor and the `gcc` command.

---

Hope this helps

Comment: Great information! This also helps me.

Comment: it helped... thanx..

Answer (score 3):

gcc describing fflush(stream), says:

> If stream points to an output stream or an update stream in which the
>   most recent operation was not input, the fflush function causes any
>   unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host environment
>   to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

fflush is not defined for output streams. It is defined for output
streams and for bidirectional streams on which the last operation was
output. `stdin` is an input stream and fflush(stdin) has no meaning.

So when you input 23 and press enter. After that `fflush` doesn't do anything. And `gets()` function just took a `\n`. Replace with it scanf.

There are lot improvement can be done in the code. Look through it.